# Blocking incoming calls and SMSes

Tags: sms, calls

I want to ask how can we block some number permanently in Windows Phone Lumia 525 such that it's not even visible in blocked messages and calls. I even don't want caller calls and messages in blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Call Forwarding (you have to order the service from the operator)
##002# - Cancel all diverts
##004# - Cancel all conditional call forwarding
**004*phone number# - Activate all conditional call forwarding

Unconditional call forwarding (Call Forward All)
###21 - Switch off and deactivate
#21# - Deactivate
**21*phone number# - Enable and Activate
*21# - Activate
*#21# - Check the condition

Diversion in case of "no answer"
###61 - Switch off and deactivate
#61# - Deactivate
**61*phone number# - Enable and Activate
*61# - Activate
*#61# - Check the condition

Setting the call time until the call forwarding option "no answer"
When installing forwarding on "no answer" you can set the time in seconds that the system allows you to hook. If during this time you have not picked up the phone, the incoming call will be diverted.
Example: - ** 61 * + ** 709576617601234 # 30 - set the waiting time of 30 seconds
Set timeout - ** 61 * Phone Number ** N #, N = 5..30 (seconds)
Remove the previous installation - ## 61 #

https://mobilespecs.net/phone/codes/Nokia/Nokia_Lumia_525.html